# Reattaching a retained cloudformation resources, back to a cloudformation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

We are retaining some of the cloudformation resources for safety reasons.

This is achieved using `DeletionPolicy: Retain`

Is there any way to reattach those retained resources to a new/existing stack?

Comment: No, i don't think there is such way. Maybe if you had all your resources in the form of `custom resources` you could build yourself such functionality, but its not there by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a new cloudformation stack or update an existing stack with resources that are not managed by Cloudformation. This is done using [Resource Import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html).

Here is the list of such resources that can be imported: [Resources that support Import operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html).

Comment: That's awesome. Didn't know about such feature. Thanks.